# Looking for Magento2 compatible Developer-Debug tool, which can be downloaded for free?

Tags: magento2, debugging, developer-mode

Please brief on the features of extension. Besides this, mention the installation process or the steps involved for enabling the module.

Answer (score 5):

You can use build in Magento 2 features : logging, xdebug support, profiler, developer mode and enable template patch hints.

**[XDebug for Magento 2](http://mageclass.com/how-to-configure-xdebug-for-magento-2-development/)** tutorial

**Enable developer mode**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

**Magento 2 Profiler**

```
SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER "html"
```

**Enable Magento 2 Template page hints** - Stores -> Configuration -> Developer

Answer (score 3):

[The Z-Ray tool](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/z-ray) from Zend Server adds to your Magento instance a toolbar with powerful features for profiling your PHP files. Using the [Magento2 Z-Ray plugin](https://github.com/magento/magento2-zray) you can track heavy constructors, blocks rendering calls, behavior extension by plugins, number of observers listening to specific event and time on their execution.

Process of installation is described in [article](http://mageclass.com/up-and-running-with-zray-for-magento2/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use XDebug for this purpose. But check the known issue with xdebug

If you use the optional PHP extension xdebug, you can encounter exceptions:

1. During installation
2. Accessing either the Magento Admin or storefront after a successful installation

**Sample exception:**

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

To resolve this issue, you can:

1. Disable the xdebug extension.
2. Set the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level to a value of 200 or more. For more information, see xdebug documentation.

After you change the configuration of or disable xdebug, restart Apache:

CentOS: sudo service httpd restart
Ubuntu: sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

I have released a developer debug toolbar for Magento 2 available on githug

[Developement Toolbar for Magento 2](https://github.com/vpietri/magento2-developer-quickdevbar)

This toolbar allow you to access information about current loaded page in tabs:

- Info : Information about controller, route, action and store. A dedicated tab output a phpinfo.
- Design : List handles called and display layout structure of nested blocks and containers
- Profile : View current observers, all events dispatched and collections, models loaded
- Queries : Statistics about executed queries and detailed query listing with syntax highlighting of main SQL keywords
- Logs : Display log files with ability to reset these files
- Actions : Easily toggle template hints and inline translation and flush cache

Answer (score 1):

I tested the best developer toolbars, I'll put down the more I liked it.

1. [ADM/QuickDevBar](https://github.com/vpietri/magento2-developer-quickdevbar)

**Info** : Information about controller, route, action and store. A dedicated tab output a phpinfo.

**Design** : List handles called and display layout structure of nested blocks and containers

**Profile** : View current observers, all events dispatched and collections, models loaded

**Queries** : Statistics about executed queries and detailed query listing 
with syntax highlighting of main SQL keywords

**Logs** : Display log files with ability to reset these files

**Actions** : Easily toggle template hints and inline translation and flush cache

2. [Mirasvit/Module-profiler](https://github.com/mirasvit/module-profiler)
3. [Balloz/Magento2-developer-toolbar](https://github.com/balloz/magento2-developer-toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

It's not free ($99), but Commerce Bug has been useful to me as I've started to get into Magento.

https://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-3

Answer (score 1):

I think, now it's quite good to use Blackfire or similar PHP-SPX with timeline view and some other metrics in addition to xDebug.

Timeline tells us a lot what going on under the hood.

https://webmageic.blogspot.com/2021/04/debug-magento-2-using-php-spx-profilers.html