# Magento 2 debugging System

Tags: magento2, error, debugging

Is there any debugging method for method magento 2 ? where we can find in which file there is actually problem occure, because making a simple spell mistake in xml file and its hard to find where is actually problem is.

Can we get file name or set break point for debugging ?

Any one have idea for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Using developer mode helps a lot for spelling mistake in XML

Comment: Please can you explain in brief because by CMD i have mode set as developer

Comment: You can find more information at [here] ( http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83536/looking-for-magento2-compatible-developer-debug-tool-which-can-be-downloaded-fo )